# PHP Looping CSV to existing Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

i want to read data from a csv an sort the input to an existing array. Than form the array to a String for, in the next step post it with curl to an existing form. The Problm is i cant get the values from the csv to the string :-( Here's my try:

```
<?php 

$datei = fopen("Testformular.csv", "r");
$data = fgetcsv($datei);

$zeilen = file("Testformular.csv");
$rows= count($zeilen);
$i=1;

while ($i <= $rows){
    list($Firma,$Anrede,$Titel,$Vorname,$Nachname,$Strasse,$PLZ,$Telefon,$Fax,$Email,$Nachricht,$CopyFlag) = fgetcsv($fp);



$fields = array(
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[name]' => urlencode(""),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[firma]' => urlencode($Firma),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[sex]' => urlencode($Anrede),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[titel]' => urlencode($Titel),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[vorname]' => urlencode($Vorname),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachname]' => urlencode($Nachname),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[strasse]' => urlencode($Strasse),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[plz_ort]' => urlencode($PLZ),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[telefon]' => urlencode($Telefon),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[fax]' => urlencode($Fax),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[email]' => urlencode($Email),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachricht]' => urlencode($Nachricht),
    'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[copy]' => urlencode($CopyFlag),
    'submit' => urlencode("Abschicken")
    );
echo "Start at Line:" .$i ."<br/>";
$i++;
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= urlencode($key).'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
print_r ($string_fields);
echo "Line" .$i ." complete <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Show us a couple of lines from the original CSV file and how the output is supposed to look like. Also in your `list` statement `fgetcsv($fp)` is not defined.

Comment: The first 2 Lines in the csv look like this: Firma,Anrede,Titel,Vorname,Nachname,Strasse,PLZ,Telefon,Fax,Email,Nachricht,CopyFlag
Testfirma1,Herr,Dr.,Vorname1,Name1,Strasse1,11111,12345567,123456,1@keine.de,nachricht1,1
What do you mean with fgetcsv($fp) is not defined? what should i do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that you are reading the file into an array three times, once from the existing file pointer using fgetcsv, then you use file() just to count the lines, and then you try to use fgetcsv on a non-existant file pointer.

Here's a quick and dirty edit of your code you can try:

(I'm assuming the CSV-fields are in the order you used in you list()-function.)

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("Testformular.csv", "r");
$line = 0;

while ( $row = fgetcsv($fp) ) {

    // Eliminate the headers
    if($line === 0){
        $line++;
        continue;
    }
    $output = "";
    $output .= 'tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[name]=' . urlencode("");
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[firma]=' . urlencode($row[0]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[sex]=' . urlencode($row[1]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[titel]=' . urlencode($row[2]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[vorname]=' . urlencode($row[3]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachname]=' . urlencode($row[4]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[strasse]=' . urlencode($row[5]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[plz_ort]=' . urlencode($row[6]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[telefon]=' . urlencode($row[7]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[fax]=' . urlencode($row[8]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[email]=' . urlencode($row[9]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachricht]=' . urlencode($row[10]);
    $output .= '&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[copy]=' . urlencode($row[11]);
    $output .= '&submit=Abschicken';

    echo "Line " . $line++ . ": " . $output . PHP_EOL;
}
```

With this content in the CSV:

```
Firma,Anrede,Titel,Vorname,Nachname,Strasse,PLZ,Telefon,Fax,Email,Nachricht,Copy‌​Flag
Testfirma1,Herr,Dr.,Vorname1,Name1,Strasse1,11111,12345567,123456,1@keine.de,nac‌​hricht1,1
```

Gives this result in my terminal:

```
Line 1: tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[name]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[firma]=Testfirma1&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[sex]=Herr&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[titel]=Dr.&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[vorname]=Vorname1&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachname]=Name1&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[strasse]=Strasse1&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[plz_ort]=11111&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[telefon]=12345567&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[fax]=123456&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[email]=1%40keine.de&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachricht]=nac%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bhricht1&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[copy]=1&submit=Abschicken
```

I put the php in a file (parsefile.php), the CSV in another file (Testformular.csv) and run it in my terminal with `php parsefile.php`

Comment: thx... hmm... looks easy, but doesnt work. Output is: 
Line 0: tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[name]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[firma]=F&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[sex]=i&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[titel]=r&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[vorname]=m&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachname]=a&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[strasse]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[plz_ort]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[telefon]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[fax]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[email]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[nachricht]=&tx_btsimplecontact_pi1[copy]=&submit=Abschicken

and this 12 Times.

Comment: so it seems that it only fetches the first line of the csv an sets the column names as the array identifiers?

Comment: Sorry, read the docs on fgetcsv wrong. edited the post to reflect correct use of fgetcsv()

Comment: hmmm... thank you very much, but this also doenst work :-( get the following error: 
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 5 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testformular.php on line 13
and so on...

Comment: I have just run this code myself on the example data you shared in the comment to your question, not getting the error you are noticing. Are you sure you copied the entire code, not just part of it, maybe missing one of the changes I did? I also added code to skip the headers you have in your file.

Comment: Wonderfull! Now it works. Many thanks to you!

Comment: You are very welcome 